# How to replace while loop with Tkinter loop

Tags: python, while-loop, tkinter

I was wandering if anyone was able to help me properly add Tkinker into my existing script?. The Tkinker code works fine outside of the current script as does the script without the Tkinter code, but I am having trouble merging it together. been doing alot of searching and i cant seem to fine the answer i am looking for. Here is the link to my script:
https://github.com/Octane70/Code/blob/master/Garden/Garden_v0.3.py

Line 50 #GUI_window is the code i am trying to add.

Thanks

Comment: The main problem is you appear to have two endless loops that need to run at the same time. The approach I would take is make the non-GUI code you now have inside the main infinite `While True:` loop into a standalone function than gets called periodically by the tkinter `mainloop()`, which must be the dominant loop in a GUI program. You can arrange for that to happen by initially issuing a call to the `root.after()` method for this new function and then doing it over again by placing another call to it at the end of the function itself.

Comment: One issue your `gui_display()` method has is that all the lines similar to `L1 = Label(root, text="Temperature=").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)` are assigning the value `None` to the variable because that's what widget `grid()` methods return. Instead you should be making separate calls; one to create the widget, and another one on a subsequent line using the object value assigned to the variable on the previous one to call its `grid()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, wandering if someone could gibe me an example or point me to somewhere I could find one? Thanks

Comment: I don't see why you need an example, just follow the advice that @Bryan and I have given you. Otherwise, you can use [google](https://www.google.com/) as well as someone else.

Comment: Rob: The update looks pretty good...congratulations. One minor optimization though. I don't think you need the `root.after(1000, gui_updates)` _inside_ the `gui_updates()` function. This is because the `Label`s should update themselves automatically whenever you change the associated `StringVar` object that was set to be their `textvariable`.

Comment: Rob: Calling `gui_updates()` more than once is actually very undesirable because it creates new `Label` objects each time (and unnecessary as per my previous comment). Get rid of the `root.after()` calls concerning it and just call it directly right before entering `root.mainloop()`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks I will give it a go. I was actually having an issue after running the code for a few hours, it would start to lag and eventually freeze. So hopefully this will solve that problem. I will let you know if it does.

Comment: Rob: Yes, calling `gui_updates()` too much could definitely have that effect. Be sure to let me know how fixing that goes (and put @martineau in the comment so I'll be sure to be notified when you have done so).

Comment: @martineau, I have updated my code and removed the root.after within my gui_updates function and moved the other just before my root.mainloop(). The lag seems to have dissapered. I still need to run it for a longer period to see if it will freeze. But so far so good. Thanks

Comment: That's good news. BTW, you don't need to use `root.after(1000, gui_updates)` at all. Just call it directly via `gui_updates()` once, right before the the `root.after(1000, updates)` and `root.mainloop()`. Probably a good idea to also rename it to something else like `gui_widgets`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `root.mainloop()` exactly once. You need to convert your `while True` loop into a function, and at the end of the function you need to call itself again with `after`. This function should also update the GUI, though you could put that in a separate function if you wish.

You do *not* want to call your `gui_display` function more than once. As it stands now, you are creating six *new* widgets every second. Instead, you want to create them once and then update them every second.